# Excel Addin Detecting if named worksheet exists and if so run Marco

Tags: vba, excel, events, worksheet

Through my addin I am trying to Detect is a named worksheet called VaR exists and if so run a macro.

In my addin ThisWorksheet Object I have included the code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Application.Run ("Macro")  

End Sub
```

It doesnt work as on opening a spreadsheet that I know has the worksheet that I am looking for e.g. "VAR" Doesnt get loaded before the addin so its not found.

Is this action possible. I only want the event to fire for users who open the workbook that contains the worksheet called "VaR".

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class to handle the event when a workbook is opened and check for the sheet in that workbook:

***Class Module (rename module to "xlApp"):***

```
Private WithEvents xlApp As Excel.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set xlApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook)

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name = "VaR" Then '// amend as required
            Call SomeMacro '// amend as required
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

***In the Workbook_Open event in your add-in:***

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim XL As xlApp
    Set XL = New xlApp
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for your time and effort